# How to evaluate this momentum conservation sum?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, combinatorics, asymptotics, distribution-theory

Consider a system enclosed in a cubic domain, of edge $L$ and volume $V = L^3$. Let $\mathbf{k}_i = \frac{2\pi}{L}(n_{xi},n_{yi},n_{zi})$, where $i = 1,2,3,4$, and $n_{xi},n_{yi},n_{zi} = 0,\pm 1, \pm 2,....$ Let the positive number $N$ be given, and let the number $k_F$ be determined by
$$\sum_{0\leq |\mathbf{k}|\leq k_{F}} 1 = N,$$ where the notation $$\sum_{0\leq |\mathbf{k}|\leq k_{F}}$$ means $$\sum_{\mathbf{k}}$$ where $\mathbf{k}$ takes on all possible values, subject to the restriction $0\leq |\mathbf{k}|\leq k_{F}$.

Question: How to calculate the sum
$$\sum_{0\leq |\mathbf{k}_{1}|\leq k_{F}} \sum_{0\leq |\mathbf{k}_{2}|\leq k_{F}} \sum_{0\leq |\mathbf{k}_{3}|\leq k_{F}} \sum_{0\leq |\mathbf{k}_{4}|\leq k_{F}} \delta (\mathbf{k}_{1} + \mathbf{k}_{2}, \mathbf{k}_{3} + \mathbf{k}_{4})$$ as a function of $N$, in the thermodynamic limit (i.e., when $N\rightarrow\infty$, $V\rightarrow\infty$, such that $\frac{N}{V} = constant$), where $\delta$ is the Kronecker symbol, i.e., $\delta (\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}) = 1$ if $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b}$, and $\delta (\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}) = 0$ if $\mathbf{a}\neq\mathbf{b}$.

**Edit**: In the thermodynamic limit one can replace the sum over $\mathbf{k}$ by an integral over $\mathbf{k}$:
$$\sum_{\mathbf{k}} f(\mathbf{k}) \longrightarrow \frac{V}{(2\pi )^3}\int f(\mathbf{k})d^3 k$$ for any integrable function $f$.

Comment: I think, in the thermodynamic limit, $$\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\,\delta_{\textbf{a},\textbf{b}}$$ should go to $$\delta^3(\textbf{a}-\textbf{b})\,,$$ where $\delta_{\textbf{a},\textbf{b}}$ is the Kronecke delta and $\delta^3(\textbf{a}-\textbf{b})$ is the $3$-dimensional Dirac delta.

Comment: Therefore, the answer should be $$\left(\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\text{vol}_9(\Omega)\,,$$ where $\text{vol}_9$ denotes the $9$-dimensional volume and $\Omega$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of $\left(\textbf{k}_1,\textbf{k}_2,\textbf{k}_3\right)$ such that $\left\|\textbf{k}_i\right\|\leq k_F$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $\left\|\textbf{k}_1+\textbf{k}_2-\textbf{k}_3\right\|\leq k_F$.  Unfortunately, this looks very ugly.

Comment: I don't think Kronecker delta goes into Dirac delta just like that. I have a better idea, namely $$\delta (\mathbf{k}_{1}, \mathbf{k}_{2}) = \frac{1}{V}\int_{V} e^{-i(\mathbf{k}_{1} - \mathbf{k}_{2})\mathbf{x}}d^3 x,$$which is an exact result. Then integrate over  $\mathbf{k}_{i}$, which is straightforward, and in the end over $\mathbf{x}$, which is not that straightforward. This is the main idea, anyway. Could somebody, please, help with the final integration over $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: @user2208 That gives exactly what I have said, in the limit $V\to\infty$.

Comment: @Batominovski The integral I wrote is valid for *any* $V$. There is no need to take the limit $V \rightarrow\infty$. As a matter of fact, this thermodynamic limit must be understood not as a strict mathematical limit, but only that $V$ is very large but finite. Otherwise one cannot pass to the limit as I wrote in EDIT. If $V$ is truly infinite, then the r.h.s is infinite, and the answer to the problem is infinite, which would be trivial.

Comment: Then good luck with that.  The integral becomes even more complex.  (And I would say that it is needlessly complicated, since for large $V$, the Dirac delta $\delta^3(\mathbf{k})$ approximates $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\,\int_V\,\exp\big(-\text{i}\,\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{x}\big)\,\text{d}^3\textbf{x}$ very well as a distribution.)

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks, it doesn't look that bad. If need be, I can always do asymptotic analysis on it taking $V$ very large but finite (the same for the cube's edge). I end up with a dimensionless integral which can be evaluated in the worst case numerically. I had hoped that someone very good with integrals would do it analytically.

Comment: Your idea is indeed good.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the required sum for large $V$ is approximately
$$I:=\left(\prod_{i=1}^4\,\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\iiint\limits_{\left\|\textbf{k}_i\right\|\leq k_F}\,\textbf{d}^3\textbf{k}_i\right)\,\left(\frac{1}{V}\,\iiint\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3}\,\text{d}^3\textbf{x}\,\exp\big(\text{i}\,\left(\textbf{k}_1+\textbf{k}_2-\textbf{k}_3-\textbf{k}_4\right)\cdot\textbf{x}\big)\right)\,.$$
That is, with $\textbf{y}:=k_F\,\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{w}_i:=s_i\,\frac{\textbf{k}_i}{k_F}$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ with $s_1=s_1=+1$ and $s_2=s_3=-1$, we get
$$I=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\iiint\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3}\,\text{d}^3\textbf{y}\,\left(\prod_{i=1}^4\,\iiint\limits_{\left\|\textbf{w}_i\right\|\leq 1}\,\text{d}^3\textbf{w}_i\,\exp\big(\text{i}\,\textbf{w}_i\cdot\textbf{y}\big)\right)\,.$$
By symmetry,
$$I=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\iiint\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3}\,\text{d}^3\textbf{y}\,\left(\iiint\limits_{\left\|\textbf{w}\right\|\leq 1}\,\text{d}^3\textbf{w}\,\exp\big(\text{i}\,\textbf{w}\cdot\textbf{y}\big)\right)^4\,.$$
Let $w:=\|\mathbf{w}\|$ and $y:=\|\mathbf{y}\|$.  For fixed $\textbf{x},\textbf{w}\neq\boldsymbol{0}$, $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ denote the angle between $\mathbf{w}$ and $\textbf{y}$.  Therefore,
$$I=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\int\limits_{0}^\infty\,4\pi y^2\,\text{d}y\,\left(\int\limits_{0}^1\,\text{d}w\,\int\limits_0^\pi\,\text{d}\theta\,\exp\big(\text{i}\,wy\cos(\theta)\big)\,2\pi w^2\sin(\theta)\right)^4\,.$$
Let $t:=\cos(\theta)$.  Then,
$$\begin{align}I&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\int\limits_{0}^\infty\,4\pi y^2\,\text{d}y\,\left(\int\limits_{0}^{1}\,\text{d}w\,\int\limits_{-1}^{+1}\,\text{d}t\,\exp\big(\text{i}\,wyt\big)\,2\pi w^2\right)^4
\\&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\int\limits_{0}^\infty\,4\pi y^2\,\text{d}y\,\left(\int\limits_{0}^{1}\,\text{d}w\,\left(\frac{2\sin(wy)}{wy}\right)\,2\pi w^2\right)^4
\\&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\int\limits_{0}^\infty\,4\pi y^2\,\text{d}y\,\left(\frac{4\pi}{y}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\,w\sin(wy)\,\text{d}w\right)^4
\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\int\limits_{0}^\infty\,4\pi y^2\,\text{d}y\,\left(\frac{4\pi}{y^3}\,\big(\sin(y)-y\cos(y)\big)\right)^4
\\
&=128\pi^2\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\int\limits_{0}^\infty\, y^2\,\left(\frac{\sin(y)-y\cos(y)}{y^3}\right)^4\,\text{d}y\,.
\end{align}$$
Using Mathematica, we obtain
$$\int\limits_0^\infty\, y^2\,\left(\frac{\sin(y)-y\cos(y)}{y^3}\right)^4\,\text{d}y=\frac{17\pi}{2835}\,,\tag{*}$$
so that
$$I=128\pi^2\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\left(\frac{17\pi}{2835}\right)=\frac{2176\pi^2}{2835}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,.$$

Since the OP wants the spatial integral to be over $[0,L]^3$, then the required sum is well approximated by 
$$J(L):=\frac{64\pi}{8}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\iiint\limits_{\left[0,k_FL\right]^3}\,\text{d}\phi\,\text{d}\vartheta\,\text{d}y\,\sin(\vartheta)\,y^2\,\left(\frac{\sin(y)-y\cos(y)}{y^3}\right)^4\,.$$
Thus,
$$J(L)\geq 8\pi\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\left(4\pi\,\int\limits_0^{k_FL}\,y^2\,\left(\frac{\sin(y)-y\cos(y)}{y^3}\right)^4\,\text{d}y\right)$$
and
$$J(L)\leq 8\pi\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\,\left(4\pi\,\int\limits_0^{\sqrt{3}\,k_FL}\,y^2\,\left(\frac{\sin(y)-y\cos(y)}{y^3}\right)^4\,\text{d}y\right)\,.$$
Hence,
$$J(L)\approx \frac{272\pi^2}{2835}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k_FL\right)^5}\right)\,.$$
Using Mathematica, the error part $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k_FL\right)^5}\right)$ lies between $-\frac{272\pi^2}{2835}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{360\sqrt{3}\,\left(k_FL\right)^5}\right)$ and $-\frac{272\pi^2}{2835}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{40 \left(k_FL\right)^5}\right)$ (for sufficiently large $L$).

If the OP mean to do the integral with the spatial part on $\left[-\frac{L}{2},+\frac{L}{2}\right]^3$, then the answer is $\tilde{J}(L)=8\,J\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)$.  We have
$$\tilde{J}(L)\approx \frac{2176\pi^2}{2835}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k_FL\right)^5}\right)\,.$$
The error $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k_FL\right)^5}\right)$ lies between $-\frac{2176\pi^2}{2835}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{45\sqrt{3}\,L^5}\right)$ and $-\frac{2176\pi^2}{2835}\left(\frac{k_F^3V}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{5 \left(k_FL\right)^5}\right)$ (for sufficiently large $L$).

The notation $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k_FL\right)^5}\right)$ is a bit deceptive.  Since $V=L^3$, we have $J(L)$ and $\tilde{J}(L)$ go like $\left(k_FL\right)^9$ for large $L$.  The error terms in fact grow like $\frac{\left(k_FL\right)^9}{\left(k_FL\right)^5}=\left(k_FL\right)^4$.

If we include the approximation of the Kronecke delta by an integral (see the first equation in my answer), then there is a larger error term for the required sum with behavior $\frac{(k_FL)^9}{(k_FL)^2}=\left(k_FL\right)^7$ for large $L$.  I have lost interest to make a proper analysis when this Kronecke delta approximation is included.  However, the point is, with this much larger error at hand, it is not reasonable to demand precision for the value of $J(L)$ or $\tilde{J}(L)$.

**P.S.**  Maybe some analyst can show how to obtain (*) manually.

Comment: $\sin\left(\, y\, \right) - y\,\cos\left(\, y\, \right) = 
{\mathrm{d}\left[\, y\,\sin\left(\, y\, \right)   \,\right] \over \mathrm{d}y.\quad}$ I don't know how this can be helpful because of the $4^{\mathrm{th}}$ power.

Comment: @Batominovski The integral over $\mathbf{x}$ is over the volume of a cube of edge $L$. For the reasons I mentioned, one has to let $L$ be large but finite. Hence one cannot integrate over the whole space and pass to spherical coordinates. One has to evaluate the triple integral from 0 to $L$ over $x,y,z$. This is the part that I don't know how to do analytically. One can reduce it to a dimensionless integral, do asymptotic analysis, and what's left evaluate numerically. If you want you can edit your answer along these steps and I will vote it since you really tried to help me.

Comment: Well, you can approximate that your cube is a bit larger than $1/8$ of a sphere of radius $L$.  Then, the integral (\*) will have upper limit $L$ instead of $\infty$.  This integral is difficult as it is, so I don't know what else can be done, apart from introducing the factor $1/8$ and maybe using Mathematica to do the final integral.  I am exhausted from thinking about (\*), so I leave it to you and other people how to best approximate it or simplify it.

Comment: Just to let you know, you will want to do this integral if you want to be as accurate as possible:
$$\iiint\limits_{\left[0,k_FL\right]^3}\,\text{d}\phi\,\text{d}\vartheta\,\text{d}y\,\sin(\vartheta)\,y^2\,\left(\frac{\sin(y)-y\cos(y)}{y^3}\right)^4\,.$$
This looks hopeless to do manually without approximation.

Comment: @Batominovski Your answer is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much! I've voted it +1 and chosen it as the right answer.